# Make custom calculated shipping methods cost for a specific country in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, country, shipping-method

i'm looking for a solution that allows me to change the cost of every shipping zones because i need to have a rounded value also in my second currency (from € to yen for Japan). I used WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip() to change the currency dynamically based on the IP adress, but i can't find a solution to change the shipping zones cost. An example to explain:

```
    $location = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();
    $country = $location['country'];
    if($country === "JP"){
    //do some code to change every shipping zone cost with a custom value
    //(different for every shipping zone)
    }
```

I hope I was clear in my explanation.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

> You may have to "**Enable debug mode**" in general shipping settings under "**Shipping options**" tab, **to disable temporarily shipping caches.**

The following code will change the shipping method cost on custom calculations for a specific country *(here Japan)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_rates_based_on_country', 20, 2 );
function custom_shipping_rates_based_on_country( $rates, $package ) {

    // ONLY for Japan
    if( $package['destination']['country'] !== 'JP' )
        return $rates;

    // Loop through shipping methods rates
    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){

        // Excluding free shipping method
        if( $rate->method_id !== 'free_shipping') {

            // Get initial shipping rate cost
            $initial_cost = $rate->cost;

            ## ---- START ------------------------------------------- ##

            // Add your calculations and settings

            // Rounding decimal setting
            $rounding_decimals = 2;

            // Conversion rate
            $conversion_rate = 1.25;

            // New calculated cost
            $new_cost = $initial_cost * $conversion_rate;

            ## ----  END  ------------------------------------------- ##

            // Set the rate cost (rounded with 2 decimals)
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = round( $new_cost, $rounding_decimals );

            // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            foreach ($rate->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rate->taxes[$key] > 0 ){

                    // Calculating the tax rate unit
                    $tax_rate = $rate->taxes[$key] / $initial_cost;

                    // Calculating the new tax cost
                    $new_tax_cost = $tax_rate * $new_cost;

                    // set the new tax cost
                    $taxes[$key] = round( $new_tax_cost, $rounding_decimals );

                    $has_taxes = true;
                } else {
                    $has_taxes = false;
                }
            }
            if( $has_taxes )
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;

        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Don't forget to enable back shipping cache.

Comment: Thankyou veru much, but can i use this to change my shipping zones price instead of my shipping method? There are a lot of countries where i send products and i can't repeat this code for everyone. Can i retrieve shipping zones setting by name and change the cost value?

Comment: @Alessio There is no prices (or costs) in shipping zones themselves, but in the shipping methods that are enabled for a shipping zone… This hook is the correct hook to make changes on shipping zones costs. It will only target "Japan" location as you can see in the answer code.